# Model.findOne is not working as expected?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, loopbackjs

```
[
  {
    "userId": "5bb6730721f28a295436b36e",
    "reputationNumber": 0,
    "questions": [],
    "answers": [],
    "id": "5bb6730721f28a295436b36f"
  },
  {
    "userId": "5bb6738c21f28a295436b370",
    "reputationNumber": 0,
    "questions": [],
    "answers": [],
    "id": "5bb6738c21f28a295436b371"
  }
]
```

I have 2 elements inside a model userDatas and i want to find a single userData by filtering with userId property.

This is what i did

```
Userdatas.findByUserId = function(req, res, cb) {
    const queryId = req.query.userId
    console.log("queryId: ",queryId);
    Userdatas.find({ userId: "5bb6738c21f28a295436b370"}, function(err, obj){
        console.log(obj);
        var userData = obj;
        cb(null, userData);
    });
}
```

Amazingly the the console output is,

```
    [ { userId: '5bb6730721f28a295436b36e',
    reputationNumber: 0,
    questions: List [],
    answers: List [],
    id: 5bb6730721f28a295436b36f },
  { userId: '5bb6738c21f28a295436b370',
    reputationNumber: 0,
    questions: List [],
    answers: List [],
    id: 5bb6738c21f28a295436b371 } ]
```

what i expect is,

```
{
    "userId": "5bb6738c21f28a295436b370",
    "reputationNumber": 0,
    "questions": [],
    "answers": [],
    "id": "5bb6738c21f28a295436b371"
  }
```

But the query works perfectly in robo mongo shell.

Comment: Have you tried running this query from a different client? I'm guessing you are accessing the wrong database/collection or being tricked by some caching issue on the client side or something.

Comment: Is your userId a string? or ObjectId? if ObjectId, can you try `Userdatas.findOne({ userId : ObjectId(queryId)}, function(err,obj) { 
    console.log(obj);    
});`

Comment: It is a string @Melvin.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result in mongoDB Shell ... have you tried that query there? It does not make a lot of sense

Comment: No, I am accessing using Node in my browser.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye it would be better if you add e2e reproduce case. Check if you have left some hardcoded values somewhere.

Comment: Well here is your example working just fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ZSA1pXwrD9

Comment: Thank you @Akiron. It also work in robo mongo shell. But it doesn't in postman and browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in loopback "find" and "findOne" functions accept queries in this pattern: {where:{queryFilters}}

so, in your example, you can change it like this:

```
Userdatas.findByUserId = function(req, res, cb) {
    const queryId = req.query.userId
    console.log("queryId: ",queryId);
    Userdatas.findOne({ where:{userId: "5bb6738c21f28a295436b370"}}, function(err, obj){
        console.log(obj);
        var userData = obj;
        cb(null, userData);
    });
}
```

Open user-datas.json under options add `"strictObjectIDCoercion": true` property.

Comment: I am on the way to post the correct answer that i got. You need to add     "strictObjectIDCoercion": true prop in options under models.json to work correctly. otherwise it will return null. So you have to update your answer like this one.